# How do I detect the last page of results when using Azure Cognitive Service Bing Web Search API?

Tags: azure, bing-api

I'm using the offset and count parameters to page through searches. I'd like to know when I reach the last page of results but it seems the Bing API can't tell me and just returns data repeated from earlier pages.

For example, using the test API at `https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56b43eeccf5ff8098cef3807/operations/56b4447dcf5ff8098cef380d/console` (you'll need an API key) you can see that the demo query for 'bill gates' suggests there are 587,000 total estimated matches.

If you change the 'offset' parameter from 0 to 700,000 (or any number that is a lot higher than the estimated) you still get results and the totalEstimatedMatches response drops to something like 540 (just five hundred and forty, no thousands).

Changing 'offset' to 500,000 yields 539 results (not 587,000 as we'd expect).

A copy of the query I am using;

```
https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search?q=bill gates&count=10&offset=500000&mkt=en-us&safesearch=Moderate
```

**How can I tell when I've reached the end of the search results if the response always insists there is more data?**

This is for a research project so yes, I really do intend to process all of the results found.